# Flutter uses LF for line endings on a windows machine

Tags: windows, git, flutter, dart

I have my git configured to autocrlf=true as recommended for Windows installations. However, when I run `flutter pub get` my `pubspeck.lock` file keeps getting lf for line endings. Is there a way to configure flutter so it respects the clrf settings?

```
# git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   pubspec.lock

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

# git diff pubspec.lock
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in pubspec.lock.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to read this.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224273/can-git-be-configured-to-not-perform-autocrlf-on-certain-files

Comment: Following your link helped. I didn't have to use a .gitattribute file. All I had to do was renormalize my repo by typing `git add --renormalize .`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by OP, the solution was:

```sh
git add --renormalize .
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:
[LF will be replaced by CRLF in git - What is that and is it important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important)

## TL;DR

do

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```